# update with join in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I want to update a column of a table1 but I should update only records where conditions are true in another table
something like this, but I don't know how to implement this purpose in Oracle SQL

```
update table1
join table2 on table1.msg_id = table2.id
set table1.index = table1.index-1
where table1.index > 10 and table2.type = 'myType'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this as an `exists` subquery in any database:

```
update table1 t1
    set index = t1.index - 1
where table1.index > 10 and
      exists (select 1
              from table2
              where t2.id = t1.msg_id and
                    t2.type = 'myType'
             );
```

The `join` sort of implies that you are going to use data from `table2` in the update of `table1`.  Instead, you simply want to change a value in a row when a particular condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not support this syntax (sigh).

For your use case, you could use a `not exists` condition with a correlated subquery instead:

```
update table1
set table1.index = table1.index - 1
where 
    table1.index > 10
    and exists (
        select 1 from table2 where table1.msg_id = table2.id and table2.type = 'mytype'
    )
```

Note: make your live easier, do not use `index` for a column name. This is a reserved work in pretty much all RDBMS.